# Fields access - polymorphic and not polymorphic types in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, vtable

When a class have virtual function in it, the compiler creates a virtual table for it. 
assume we have the code above:

```
class A {
public: 
int x;
};

class B : public A {
virtual void foo(){}
};
```

now B has a vtable while A does not. 
if we have a function that return a pointer to A which can be an A or a B, and we access x field of the object that the function has returned.
how the compiler does the adjustment to access x, it must be done at runtime, but how ?

Comment: A quick compile to asm would probably answer your question, but accessing `x` isn't a runtime-determinate. Theres nothing virtual about member *variables* in the hierarchy you presented. It has a determinate offset from instances of B (or A), and that doesn't change just because `foo` is virtual.

Comment: Note that the C++ standard does not require use of vtables. More dynamic schemes are possible. Also, a compiler using vtables, as I believe all extant commonly used compilers do, doesn't need to add a vtable pointer at the start of `B`. It's entirely up to each compiler how to do it. Except to the degree that the compiler must conform to system requirements.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But no other scheme comes even close to the efficiency of vtables, and the simplicity in the single inheritance case.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `A*` pointer returned by the function you mention, there's no adjustment: it's already an `A*`, it points directly to an `A` object, which can be the `A` base class sub-object of a `B` object.

However, there can and will typically be a **pointer value adjustment** in the return logic of the function you mention that produces an `A*` pointing to a `B` object.

That's because `B` will typically have a vtable pointer at the start, so that the `A` base class sub-object is not at offset 0. The necessary adjustment makes it possible to screw up by effectively doing a `reinterpret_cast` that doesn't adjust. And that can happen with a simple-minded deleter for a `unique_ptr` (a `shared_ptr` is smarter about it, at some cost).

---

Example:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B: A
{
    virtual void foo(){}
    B( const int value ): A{ value } {}
};

B b_object( 42 );

auto ptr()
    -> A*
{
    return &b_object;
}       

#include <iostream>
auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "&b_object  = " << &b_object << ".\n";
    cout << "As A* it's = " << ptr() << ".\n";
    cout << b_object.x << " in B, is " << ptr()->x << " in A.\n";
}
```

Result with MinGW g++ 7.3.0 in Windows 10:

```
&b_object  = 0x512030.
As A* it's = 0x512038.
42 in B, is 42 in A.
```

You can see from the addresses that the extra info at the start of a `B` is 8 bytes, consistent with that info being an 8-byte pointer value, for this 64-bit compiler.